# Can't evaluate if variable equals a specific number

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want to write a condition that returns true if:

```
.Values.pdb.enabled == true
and 
.Values.replicas != 1
```

This throws an error I don't understand:

```
{{- if and (eq .Values.pdb.enabled true) (ne .Values.replicas 1) }}
```

Error:

```
... at <ne .Values.replicas "1">: error calling ne: incompatible types for comparison
```

I also tried wrapping 1 in quotes.

This is the problem: `ne .Values.replicas 1`

I also tried this but I get the same error for the `lt` function: `lt .Values.replicas 2`

Comment: In your `values.yaml` file, what is the value of `replicas:` (if any)?

Comment: in my default values.yaml I have `replicas: 1`

Comment: The error looks as if the 1 used in the comparison was interpreted as string. Have you tried casting it to int?

Comment: That worked. I feel dumb for not trying that. I guess I assumed because I didn't have it wrapped in quotes in the values yaml it would properly read it as an int. Does helm/sprig just treat all inputs as strings unless you tell it otherwise?